# comma separated in text file in php

Tags: php

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
 {
    $file = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $fh = fopen($file,'r+');

// string to put username and passwords
$users = '';

while(!feof($fh)) {

    $user = explode(' ',fgets($fh));

    foreach ($user as $value) 
    {
        $number= rand(1000,10000);
        $final_number[] = $value .','. $number;

    }

}

//print_r($final_number);
file_put_contents($_FILES['file']['name'], $final_number);

}
```

this is my code for appending a random text to a string with comma and save it in text file but when i am saving it it is not saving properly after comma it is going to next line which should not happen plzz.. help me

Comment: You could try to trim() $value in your foreach loop

Comment: @Drakes is correct. The above code doesn't produce the expected output because the CR/LF from the input line is included in the assignment to $final_number (eg. = '"last field of line"\n,added random value')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code starts with a very big issue: you try to open and read from a file that, most probably, doesn't exist.

```
$file = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$fh = fopen($file,'r+');
```

As you can read in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php), assuming that your form contains an `input` element of type `file` having the name `file`, `$_FILES['file']['name']` is the original name of the uploaded file, on the user's computer. It is only the name and it **is not** the name of the file on the server. It is provided just as a hint for the file's content (check the filename extension) but you cannot rely on it.

The content of the file is temporarily stored on the webserver in a file whose path can be found in `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']`. You should pass it to the PHP function [`is_uploaded_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-uploaded-file.php) to be sure the file was uploaded and your script is not the victim of an injection attempt then, if you need to keep it, use [`move_uploaded_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) to move it where you need. If you don't move it, when your script ends the temporary file is deleted.

Another problem of your code is on the lines:

```
$user = explode(' ',fgets($fh));
foreach ($user as $value)
```

As explained in the documentation, the function [`fgets()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php) called without a second argument reads a line from the input file, including the newline character that ends it. Since you split the line into words I think you don't need the newline character. You can remove it by using [`trim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) with the string returned by `fgets()` before passing it to `explode()`.

The last issue of the code is:

```
file_put_contents($_FILES['file']['name'], $final_number);
```

Because `$final_number` is an array<sup>1</sup>, [`file_put_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) joins its elements to get a string and writes the string into file. This operation concatenates the random value generated for a `$value` with the next `$value` and there is no way to tell which is which after the data is stored in the file. You probably need to keep them on separate lines. Use function [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) on `$final_number`, with `"\n"` as its first argument and write the generated string into the file instead.

The last one: **don't** write the generated content to `$_FILES['file']['name']`. It is not safe! It contains a string received from the browser; a malicious user can put whatever path they want there and your script will overwrite a file that it shouldn't change.

Create a directory dedicated to store files generated by your code and generate filenames based on an always incremented counter (the current `time()` or `microtime()` f.e.) for the files you store there. **Never** trust the data you receive from the browser.

---

<sup>1</sup> `$final_number` is used as `$final_number[] = ...` and, because it is not defined when this line of code is executed for the first time, PHP creates an empty array for you and stores it in `$final_number`. **Don't** rely on this feature. Always initialize your variables before their first use. Put `$final_number = array();` before the `while()`.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to use a different approach than you, let's say that the data you want to save to the file is stored in the variable `$data`.

So to append this data to the file with a comma at first, we can use just two lines of code:

```
$previousFileContent = file_get_contents("filename.txt");
file_put_contents("filename.txt", trim($previousFileContent . "," . $data));
```

Comment: OP want's to append some data to each line in the file

Comment: The data you want to insert, i.e. `$final_number` in your case